# How to sync podcasts between two computers?

Tags: iphone, itunes, sync, podcasts

I want to share only podcasts between two computers, without music and videos, is there any solution of sharing iTunes podcasts?

Comment: related - http://superuser.com/questions/151/how-to-keep-itunes-libraries-in-sync .. but not sure how to get *just* podcasts, and not the whole shebang

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. I hate iTunes, and I love it..  :)

Answer (score 1):

can you not just add the subscription for the podcasts on both computers?

Comment: But I have to download twice, it takes too long since network here is poor